# remove secondary IP on interface ubuntu 19.04 permanently

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

I have a strange problem: I have 2 IP Adresses configured and I can't remove it, neither I know where it is configured.

```
> ip a s enp6s0
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:31:bf:6a:cd:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.3/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global enp6s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.178.114/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute enp6s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I do have configured a static IP in */etc/network/interfaces*, but no secondary IP at all:

```
## The primary network interface
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet static
  address 192.168.178.3/24
  gateway 192.168.178.1
  dns-nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

the /var/log/syslog shows, that somehow a DHCP address is assigned to the Interface:

```
Jul 14 12:33:03 hogwarts dhcpcd[1897]: enp6s0: leased 192.168.178.114 for 864000 seconds
Jul 14 12:33:03 hogwarts dhcpcd[1897]: enp6s0: adding route to 192.168.178.0/24
Jul 14 12:33:03 hogwarts dhcpcd[1897]: enp6s0: adding default route via 192.168.178.1
```

deleting it manually is unsuccessful

```
ip a d 192.168.136.114/32 dev enp6s0
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
```

I can't find any systemd/initd skript being responsible for this IP being added.

What I already checked:

- I already configured systemd to "debug" to be more verbose, but no
  luck.
- No netplan config exits
- disabled NetworkManager in systemctl

Any ideas are appreciated!

System: Ubuntu 19.04 Server, upgraded from 18.04 LTS -> 18.10 -> 19.04

Answer (score 4):

-> Antons point 2.) lead me to the solution:

somehow dhcpcd was running (hope neither docker nor virtualbox needs it) and everytime I deleted the IP with Antons point 1), it was obviously created once again.

so my solution is

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
systemctl stop dhcpcd.service
ip a d 192.168.178.114/24 dev enp6s0
```

Thx!

Comment: Ubuntu since at least 18.04 uses netplan for network configuration. If you have a static IP I'd recommend setting it up in /etc/netplan and set dhcp4 to false, then `netplan apply` instead of hacking your way around.

Comment: I‘ll dig into this and would update the answer accordingly, Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the previous versions, from Ubuntu 18.04 uses **Netplan** utility. In this new approach, we no longer use *`/etc/network/interfaces`* to configure IP address. The default configuration files of Netplan are located in **`/etc/netplan`** folder.

So in order to find out the default network configuration file:

```
ls /etc/netplan/
```

By default, it should be ***50-cloud-init.yaml*** file. Read that config yaml file

```
cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

In my case, the default config file look like this:

```
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

My network card name is enp2s0 and yours maybe different ( like eth0 or wlan0 or something like that). If you have 2 Ip addresses, check second files in the folder **netplan**. Just delete it.

After all, apply your changes

```
sudo netplan try
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot remove that address because you specify incorrect prefix length. You should run `ip address del 192.168.136.114/24 dev enp6s0` (not `192.168.136.114/32`). But it doesn't have a permanent effect.
2. If your address is assigned with dhcp, you should have running dhcp client. Try to find it with `ps aux | grep dhc` command.
3. To monitor the changes of network configuration run `ip monitor address` command.
4. Check the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory. It can contain additional configuration files.
5. Old way of configuration of static and dhcp addresses on the same interface simultaneously is specification of additional alias in the `interfaces` file. Try find something like that:

```
auto enp6s0:1
iface enp6s0:1 inet dhcp
```

6. Do you have the running `systemd-networkd` service? Check it with `systemctl status systemd-networkd.service` command.

Comment: -> 1.) no, doesn't work.
-> 2.) *but* as long it is not configured within "interfaces" to use dhcp, it shouldn't assign an address
-> 4.) /etc/network/interfaces.d/ is empty
-> 5.) actually I don't want 2 addresses, I just want only the static one

Comment: 1. Likely it doesn't work because currently you have another ip address. 2. Check the systemd-networkd service.